Get an altool exited with code 1 when trying to publish on the Apple Store
I have already published a few times my Maui app to the Apple Store from Visual Studio 2022. After the upgrade to version 17.9.7 of Visual Studio, I can't deploy and the error I get is

App Store bundle validation failed for archive ...
"altool" exited with code 1


I increased the version of my app in the Info.plist and checked that the configuration in the project was correct

I saw this post on Stackoverflow and the Microsoft documentation.
Update
This is the Xcode I'm using


You need to get the detailed errors from the command.  Are you sure you are building with Xcode 15?

According to the workaround in the link, can you publish the MAUI project through Xcode?
